# fetch data using stored procedure in entity framework

Tags: asp.net, web-services

```
 i want to fetch data from database using stored procedure in web service,
error is i am unable to fetch particular column data using foreach loop.
```

variable item does not have any column name. please help me what can i do for getting data from SP.

```
public string GetAllUniqueNumberBySP()
    {

        using (SoubhagyatechEntities dbcontext = new SoubhagyatechEntities())
        {
         var data = dbcontext.SP_getALLUniqueCode().ToList();
         foreach (var item in data)
         {
            var s= item.assetmasterAssetUniqueId;
         }
return s;
        }

    }
```

Comment: you have declared var s in foreach loop and returning from outside

Comment: that is not my problem, i will correct it, my problem is when i access the column name using "item.assetmasterAssetUniqueId", it shows an error.

Comment: What error? Can you please tell

Comment: Error 12 'string' does not contain a definition for 'assetmasterAssetUniqueId' and no extension method 'assetmasterAssetUniqueId' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Can you share your stored proc's select command?

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE SP_getALLUniqueCode  
AS  
BEGIN  
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from  
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
  
    -- Insert statements for procedure here  
    Select assetmasterAssetUniqueId from tblassetmaster  
END  
GO

Comment: This is a Scalar Single valued Result. So you can get it directly in item; If there were more than 1 columns in select statement then the column names can be accessed by using like property names